# Representing time differences in Ruby

Tags: ruby, time

Does Ruby stdlib have any objects that represent difference between two timestamps? Subtracting two `Time` object from each other returns a float number of seconds - is there any object for that, with methods like `hours`, `minutes` etc., and most of all decent `to_s`?

I've coded half-assed methods for that far too many time, am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Why not write the class properly once and reuse every time you need it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not in the stdlib, but there is a Gem that you can use for the job - the [duration](http://rubyforge.org/projects/duration) gem.

```
sudo gem install duration
```

Which you can use like this:

```
require "duration"
a = Time.now
sleep(5)
b = Time.now
duration = Duration.new(b - a)
# => #<Duration: 5 seconds>
duration.seconds
# => 5
duration.minutes
# => 0
```

And days, hours, weeks and a bunch of other useful methods.

You can also then monkey-patch Time, Date and other date-time classes to return Duration objects.

Answer (score 1):

perhaps [duration](http://rubyforge.org/projects/duration) does help? [Here](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/136004) is an announcement for it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a gem called [time_diff](https://rubygems.org/gems/time_diff) which return a hash of difference in year, month, week, day, hour, minute, second