# Ruby Time manipulation

Tags: ruby, time

I need to verify if the difference between a saved Time object and Time.Now is greater than 780 seconds.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: What about this one:
[Time Difference in Ruby][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3275682/representing-time-differences-in-ruby

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (Time.now - old_time > 780) ...
```

[Time - operator docs](http://apidock.com/ruby/Time/-)

```
puts Time.now - old_time
```

Comment: Ok... and how can if print out (Time.now - old_time) value? I have
puts (Time.now - old_time).to_s but I get this error: "no implicit conversion to float from string"

Comment: @content01 I don't get that error; what version of Ruby are you using?